# htacces rewrite url - remove folder name from url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm tryng to make an htaccess url rewrite for this cases:

```
www.website.com/index.php/admin/something => www.website.com/admin/something
www.website.com/index.php/website/something => www.website.com/something
www.website.com/index.php/login/something => www.website.com/login/something
```

note: "something" can be "something1/something2/something3" or "something1/something2" or "something"

I can cut "index.php" with:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

but I can't found a way to remove only "website/" and not "admin/" and "login/" leaving the rest of url.

Answer (score 0):

If taking this approach you will probably have to specify each possible input reference that should not be mapped to your 'website' controller and remap it to index.php/$1 and treat every other request like it is a method of the website controller, mapping it to index.php/website/$1

Something like the below will map anything starting with admin or login to index.php and everything else to the website controller:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^admin.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^login.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/website/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I'm getting a 500 error for all the pages with this code... I'm tryng to figure out a solution with this:  RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(website/) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ website/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index./php|resources|robots.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  in this case I everything works fine for /website but not for admin/ or login/